# How do I calculate the size of my pointer array in C?

Tags: c

```
{
    void print(char *p[]);
    char *name[] = { "11111","2222222","33333333" };
    printf("sizeof name:%d\n",sizeof(name));// output 24
    print(name);
    return 0;
}
void print(char *p[])
{
    printf("sizeof p:%d\n",sizeof(p)); // output 8
}
```

I do not know output different. i think it is should equal,but i do not know why pointer array as argument different?

Comment: Because passing array to function decays to pointer. You will have to pass the length of the array as an argument explicitly .

Comment: Yesterday I answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62005639/11336762 .